# Reactive Loading in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, load, reactive, rdata

Given a data set

```
a<-1
b<-2
c<-42
d<- a+b*c

save(file="data.RData",list=ls())
```

I want to be able to load them **once** with a reactive load and be able to use them as many time as I want

My code looks like

```
ui_test <- shinyUI({

fluidPage(fluidRow(
fileInput(inputId = "generated_data",label=NULL,buttonLabel= h4(strong("Load your data here")),accept = ".RData",placeholder = NULL),
    hr(),
    verbatimTextOutput("test1"),
    verbatimTextOutput("test2"),
    verbatimTextOutput("test3")
  ))  
})

server_test <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  observeEvent(input$generated_data,{
    load(input$generated_data$datapath)
  })

  output$test1<-renderText({if (!is.null(input$generated_data)) a+b else "No input"})
  output$test2<-renderText({if (!is.null(input$generated_data)) c else "No input"})
  output$test3<-renderText({if (!is.null(input$generated_data)) d else "No input"})
})

shinyApp(ui=ui_test,server=server_test)
```

but it doesn't seem to work when I upload the RData file

> Warning: Error in renderText: object 'b' not found

Comment: Hey @K.Hua, tried your code after removing `buttonLabel`, no problems faced